# Why was the [Serializable] attribute removed from Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I am working on migrating a WinForms class library to Windows Phone, but I am coming across a change that seems to have real effect.

The code works as it stands, there is just common logic, but the classes in WinForms are all attributed with `[Serializable]`. However, the attribute does not exist in Windows Phone or Windows Store Apps. Is there a reason this was omitted? This is the same for the `ISerializable` interface. In the list at the bottom of the MSDN docs, it does actually include both Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.

I do not understand why these type were removed as they are both helpful as well as very generic.

Comment: Who knows? You should probably ask the people that wrote the code. I'd try on MSDN. StackOverflow is not a good forum for this.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you say "removed"? i doubt if it ever existed to begin with.

There are a bunch of unsupported features in the WinRT & Silverlight (WP7/WP8) stacks like:
(not sure what is Microsoft's timeline to get these)

1. XSD to class handling
2. Binary Formatting/Serialization etc.

The **`Serializable`** attribute is used only for Binary Serialization. (and not for XmlSerialization etc.) Because Binary Serialization etc. are not supported, you may not see the full stack of classes available in WP8 libraries including this attribute.

If you have Serialization needs, use **`XmlSerialization`** or **`DataContractSerializer`**.

And if nothing other than Binary works for you, i think there is some 3rd party library **sharpSerializer** (haven't used it)